# Morris Klein Tangent on Parabola X intersection Question

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, conic-sections, tangent-line

Im currently trying to solve a Math Exercise from the book "Morris Kline - Calculus An Intuitive and Physical Approach" and iv been struggling to get a grip on it.

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkemX.png)

I think i know how to solve it but there is that missing puzzle piece that eludes me.
My thought process was Finding the derivative of the slope thus finding out the slope of the line that will intersect the X Axis...but this is where i got stuck. I cant figure out how to use the Ecuation of a Line to prove the Exercise.

Can someone help me please?

[Sample Graph i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR9U3.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Once you have the equation of the tangent line, find its intersection with the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

HINT... let the $x$ abscissa be $2pt$ where $t$ is a parameter, so the corresponding $y$ value is $pt^2$. Then write down the equation of the tangent at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer David!i figured it out using ur help but i feel like i would have never had the ideea that you had. Do you have any tips on how i could improve myself and have such insights?

Comment: parametric representation of curves is very useful if you want to prove general geometric properties of the curve because using generalized coordinates means you are proving the property for **every** point on the curve at once.

Comment: Thank you again David, i wish you all the best.

Comment: you are welcome